# Correct use of Prism navigation service in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, service, xamarin.forms, navigation, prism

I want to confirm if I am using the prism navigation service with xamarin forms correctly. I have a master detail page, a styled navigation page and a bunch of content pages.

right now I am using the service in the following way:

```
            var prj = await dataService.GetLwdProject(appState.SelectedProjectId);
            var nparam = new NavigationParameters();
            nparam.Add("Project", prj);
            await NavigateTo("RootPage/StyledNavigationPage/SessionsListPage", nparam);
```

Where the Master detail page is the RootPage object. So expecting that when a user selects an item from this list page the correct way to the service should be:

```
                var nparma = new NavigationParameters();
                nparma.Add("Session", option);
                await App.NavigateTo("RootPage/StyledNavigationPage/SessionsListPage?ProjectId=" + option.ProjectId + "/LocationListPage", nparma);
```

What I expect that just a LocationListPage would be added to the navigation stack, but when I use the the hardware back button on android it looks like that not only the last page was added but the whole path (all pages). So is this the correct way auto construct the desired path?

Answer (score 0):

No. Navigation is always relative to where you are calling it.  What you have now will navigate to the entire deep link you have created every time. Just navigate to your target NavigationPage/SessionListPage and pass your parameter. Though, you won't get a new page every time in this case, since you are navigating to the same view, but just passing different state.

Comment: The reason I construct the whole patch is that is the only way I have found that create the page in the expected way.  on the path:
RootPage/StyledNavigationPage/SessionsListPage it is essentially a master detail page  with a navigation page pointing to SessionsListPage, If I just write navigate to LocationListPage only a simple content page is shown, so no naviagion bar or access to the master detail page. The only way back is using the hardware back button. If I express it like :StyledNavigationPage/LocationListPage, I will get the navigation back but no back button.

Comment: You're not doing it correctly. To achieve your desired behavior, your NavigationPage should implement INavigationPageOptions and set the ClearNavigationStackOnNavigation property to false.  Now when you navigation from your MasterDetail, as long as you prefix the Detial with your navigationPage it will not reset the stack but rather push each page onto the stack.